# Change only one value in a deep object

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem with the manipulation of object. I want to change the value of a key, but I don't know how to modificate this value without knowing the value of is parent object.

My exemple will speak for me.

My object look like that :

```js
{day: {
   monday: {
      startTime: 2, 
      endTime: 1
  }
}}
```

I want to change the "startTime" value, I know I can do :

```js
{day: {monday:{starTime: [value]}}}
```

But the problem is, that I don't know the second key (it can be any day of the week). Like

```js
{know: {
    unknow: {
        know: valueToChange
    }
}}
```

Do you know a trick for that ?

Comment: Will there only be a single property in that object?

Comment: No, it can be between 1 and 7, and I don't know that too

Comment: So if there are 7, which one do you want to change? All of them?

Comment: It was only for one, @Evgency give me a solution thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go over all values there and change each by iteration:

```js
const data = {
  day: {
    monday: {
      startTime: 2, 
      endTime: 1
    },
    tuesday: {
      startTime: 2, 
      endTime: 1
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(data.day).forEach(key => {
  data.day[key].startTime = 10 // some known value
})

console.log(data)
```

This way you can change all of them or you can check if there is some specific key you want to change if you don't want to change all of them

Answer (score 0):

This can also be one of the many Solution.We can use recursion

```js
let data = {
            day: {
                monday: {
                    startTime: 1,
                    endTime: 1
                }
            }
        };

        function getStartTime(data) {
            if (data.startTime) {
                data.startTime = 6;
            } else {
                getStartTime(Object.values(data)[0]);
            }
        }
        getStartTime(data);
        console.log(data);
```